# view not taking the full width

Tags: android, xml

In my app i am using recyclerview.I want customize list data so i have made a custom adapter.Now the problem is that the view appears to be of full width in the preview window of android studio but on the device its not full width so my half data is getting cutted.

XMl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="#EDEFF1">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_g_name"
        style="@style/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Ashton Kutcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_g_del"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cancellation" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView33"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_g_name"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_g_del"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/iv_g_del"
        android:background="#D6D7D9" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_g_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView33"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView33"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cancellation" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView34"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView33"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_g_add"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/iv_g_add"
        android:background="#D6D7D9" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView35"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iv_g_add"
        android:background="#D6D7D9" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView35"
        android:paddingBottom="05dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="05dp"
        android:paddingTop="05dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cancellation" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_g_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView35"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="pavanh.dev@gmail.com" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_g_email"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_g_email"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_g_email"
        android:paddingBottom="05dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="05dp"
        android:paddingTop="05dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cancellation" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_g_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView35"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView6"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="889845412" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please let me know where i went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use Padding in Parent instead of margin like below and also check padding and margin of your ListView which may stop View Rendering Full width

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_paddingRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="#EDEFF1">
       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_g_name"
        style="@style/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Ashton Kutcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_g_del"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cancellation" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView33"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_g_name"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_g_del"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/iv_g_del"
        android:background="#D6D7D9" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_g_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView33"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView33"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cancellation" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView34"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView33"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_g_add"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/iv_g_add"
        android:background="#D6D7D9" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView35"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iv_g_add"
        android:background="#D6D7D9" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView35"
        android:paddingBottom="05dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="05dp"
        android:paddingTop="05dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cancellation" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_g_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView35"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="pavanh.dev@gmail.com" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_g_email"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_g_email"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_g_email"
        android:paddingBottom="05dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="05dp"
        android:paddingTop="05dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cancellation" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_g_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView35"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView6"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="889845412" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it may add spaces at start and end of View

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
android:background="#EDEFF1">
```

Comment: `fill_content`=`wrap_content`, isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `fill_parent` instead of `match_parent`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="#EDEFF1">
```

And in 1st TextView, you have forgotten mentioning the namespace `android:style`. Please rectify that.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="#EDEFF1">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_g_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Ashton Kutcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_g_del"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView33"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_g_name"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_g_del"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/iv_g_del"
        android:background="#D6D7D9" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_g_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView33"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView33"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView34"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView33"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_g_add"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/iv_g_add"
        android:background="#D6D7D9" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView35"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iv_g_add"
        android:background="#D6D7D9" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView35"
        android:paddingBottom="05dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="05dp"
        android:paddingTop="05dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_g_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView35"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="pavanh.dev@gmail.com" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_g_email"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_g_email"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_g_email"
        android:paddingBottom="05dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="05dp"
        android:paddingTop="05dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_g_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView35"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView6"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="889845412" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the recyclerview, you normally have the layout for the individual items in the list and then the layout that contains the actual recyclerview. The layout for the actual recyclerview might have contain some type of padding or margin which is why it doesn't fill up the screen.

You will need to check that layout and not the layout for the individual items in the list.

You have also not posted the layout that contains the recyclerview so we are not able to evaluate.